# Do we need a "flicker" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reviewing old [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag questions this morning, and I came upon this one which is tagged with [flicker](/questions/tagged/flicker):

[Why is there a flicker when swapping an inner Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633201/flicker-when-swapping-inner-panel-java-awt)

Do we need a tag like this?  I think it's unlikely that someone would be an expert in solving cross-language flicker problems.  Wouldn't it be better to just tag it with the appropriate technologies, in this case [awt](/questions/tagged/awt), [java](/questions/tagged/java), and the like?

I have reviewed a sampling of the 310 questions tagged as [flicker](/questions/tagged/flicker) and this tag doesn't seem to be useful.  Is there an easy way for administrators to just remove all instances of a tag like this?  Or should they all be reviewed manually and have their tags re-adjusted?

Comment: It should be merged into [doublebuffered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffered)...and while we're at it, same goes for [doublebuffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffering). ...Or we create a new tag: `double-buffer` as target for this.

Comment: I'm tempted to make `flicker` a synonym of `awt`.  ;p  (Unfortunately the correlation isn't strong enough.)

Comment: Some appear to be misspelled (ironically) tags for Flickr. Flickr *is* a valid tag, don't know of any other revelevant users though.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby Are all of the flickering problems due to double-buffering?  I like that this would help users who tag their question with flickering get to the double-buffered community.

Comment: @BenBrocka I fixed those mis-taggings.

Comment: @ErickRobertson: Those tags are already borderline, and `flicker` is for sure not valid, `double-buffer` would at least be a related, half-valid tag. And yes, I'd argue that 99% of all cases when something flickers that it can be fixed or is related to double-buffering, the other 1% are stuff like vsync, interlacing and broken video files.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby I think the biggest argument for getting rid of all those tags is that double-buffering is a *solution* word.  Many people who are having this type of problem won't know to tag their question this way.